# fd limit warning after jboss upgrade to WIldfly

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, application-server

Recently , I upgraded my JBOSS from version 6 to 8.2.0 (Wildfly). After the upgrade , I can see the following logs in server startup :

> WARN  [org.jboss.as.warn.fd-limit] (main) JBAS015972: The operating
>   system has limited the number of open files to 1024 for this process;
>   a value of at least 4096 is recommended

If I understand correctly, Wildfly Jboss recommends the  number of open file count to  be set to 4096. Does this also indirectly mean Wildfly Jboss will be opening up more files than the earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

File descriptors are also used for sockets. While you might think 1024 is a lot of files if you consider all the open sockets, all the JAR's the JVM has open, all JAR's WildFly has to open, etc. you can see where it would add up fairly quickly.

Comment: I can see open file issues after Jboss upgrade sometimes,  so was looking  out for some pointers on whether Jboss really is opening up more files ?

Comment: Itis actually opening less than AS6 did. But warning was added as general guideline

Comment: It's not opening that many files. On a default install of WildFly 10 I've got it using 801 file descriptors. You can use `ps -a -p <pid>` to see all the files and sockets that are open.